# Why isn't CodeIgniter autoloading my package?

Tags: php, codeigniter, package, autoload, autoloader

In my `application/config/config.php`, I want to autoload my library package:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Packges
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|  $autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party', '/usr/local/shared');
|
*/

$autoload['packages'] = array('../../lib');
```

The relative path did not work, so I got the current directory of my `index.php` and tried that:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(getcwd() . '/../../lib');
```

Finally, I just stuck the absolute path in there:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array('/Users/.../lib');
```

None of these worked. Am I missing something? Because [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) is quite sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I added a modified autoloader right before the `require_once` statement in `index.php`:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if (strstr($class, 'CI') || strstr($class, 'MY')) {
        return;
    }

    $class = ltrim($class, '\\');
    $filename  = '';
    $namespace = '';

    if ($last_ns_pos = strripos($class, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($class, 0, $last_ns_pos);
        $class = substr($class, $last_ns_pos + 1);
        $filename  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    $filename .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

    require strtolower($filename);
});
```

The original autoloader can be found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/).

Honestly, no matter what I tried with CodeIgnitier, loading third-party packages or drivers just would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago. I had to create a library to load a driver. I fixed it with the following.

In `/application/config.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('callcache');
//callcache is loaded from application/libraries/Callcache.php
```

In `/application/libraries/Callcache.php`

```
<?php
class Callcache  {
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps you out, even though you're trying to load a package and not a driver (via a library). I can't remember where I found the info for this and still learning CI myself.

Comment: I'll look into it today.